# General Curiosity: Use of $L^p$ spaces when $0<p<1$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

I often come across the space $L^p[0,1]$ for $0<p<1$.  Do these have any uses besides examples of non-locally-convex spaces?  If so what?

Comment: I don't see why this legitimate question should be closed. If there is any specific reason, some comment would be welcome.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing..